# Android WebView - Fatal Signal 6

Tags: java, android, webview, fatal-error

I create a `WebView` in every new activity which is created, but I always destroy the one in the previous activity. I am getting `Fatal Signal 6` only when I open multiple activities (5-6). This is what is being shown in the `LogCat`

```
08-07 12:41:06.482: W/BindingManager(659): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 659
08-07 12:41:06.582: W/BindingManager(659): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 659
08-07 12:41:08.122: W/Adreno-GSL(659): <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1498>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
08-07 12:41:08.122: E/Adreno-GSL(659): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2042>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
08-07 12:41:08.122: W/Adreno-GSL(659): <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1498>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
08-07 12:41:08.122: E/Adreno-GSL(659): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2042>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
08-07 12:41:08.132: W/Adreno-GSL(659): <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1498>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
08-07 12:41:08.132: E/Adreno-GSL(659): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2042>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
08-07 12:41:08.132: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <core_glTexImage2D:539>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
08-07 12:41:08.132: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.142: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.142: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.142: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.142: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.142: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.142: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.172: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <core_glClear:37>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.172: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.172: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.172: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.172: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.172: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.172: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.172: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.562: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <core_glClear:37>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.562: E/OpenGLRenderer(659): GL error: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.582: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <core_glClear:37>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.582: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.592: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.592: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.592: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.592: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:08.592: E/chromium(659): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2009)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:7C4CFD60]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::RestoreStateForTextures: <- error from previous GL command
08-07 12:41:08.592: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <gl_draw_error_checks:498>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:09.202: W/Adreno-ES20(659): <core_glClear:37>: Error: Unknown: 0x506
08-07 12:41:09.202: E/OpenGLRenderer(659): GL error: 0x506
08-07 12:41:09.702: W/Adreno-GSL(659): <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:1498>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
08-07 12:41:09.702: E/Adreno-GSL(659): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2042>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
08-07 12:41:09.722: A/chromium(659): [FATAL:memory.cc(18)] Out of memory. size=9195520
08-07 12:41:10.542: W/google-breakpad(659): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
08-07 12:41:10.542: W/google-breakpad(659): Chrome build fingerprint:
08-07 12:41:10.542: W/google-breakpad(659): 1.2
08-07 12:41:10.542: W/google-breakpad(659): 6
08-07 12:41:10.542: W/google-breakpad(659): 873fd9bc-5759-4679-9dc5-2d671bd0c1b7
08-07 12:41:10.552: W/google-breakpad(659): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
08-07 12:41:10.552: E/chromium(659): ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.90 (code 240309000)
08-07 12:41:10.552: A/libc(659): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 957 (Thread-5922)
```

This is the code of my `WebView` (Fragment)

```
WebView webview;
WebSettings webview_settings;
webview_ad = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview_ad);
webview_ad_settings = webview_ad.getSettings();

Context context = rootView.getContext();

String url = "http://www.example.com";
webview_ad.loadUrl(url);

webview_settings = webview.getSettings();
webview_settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And this is the code I call `onPause()` on every activity

```
WebViewFrag fragment = (WebViewFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WebView");
WebView webview = fragment.returnWebView();

if(webview != null) {

    webview.pauseTimers();
    webview.stopLoading();  
    webview.clearAnimation();
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    webview.removeAllViews();
    webview.clearFocus();
    webview.destroy();

}
```

I also have added both `android:largeHeap="true"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on `Manifest`. I am testing the application on a real device on Galaxy Note 3. Is there any explanation why I am getting `Fatal Signal 6` and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am getting a similar error. Have you found a fix or workaround?